# Breathing New Life [Part 5]

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking, wordplay, rhyme, poetry

This is the final part of a 5 part series.

Links to the first 4:

Part 1: [Large and in charge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28209/large-and-in-charge)  [solved]

Part 2: [Small and resilient](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28262/small-and-resilient)  [solved]

Part 3: [Immovable object](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28306/immovable-object)  [solved]

Part 4: [Unstoppable force](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28360/unstoppable-force)  [solved]

(parts 1-4 can be solved out of order)

---

### Now for Part 5:

Part 1---

A good problem solver peers into the past,
once you find me, it's quiet at last.

Completing this riddle is the ultimate test,
for after its done, you will need your rest.

Part 2---

The other day I screamed "JSTYX" out loud all confused,
To figure out what it means, I'd be greatly amused.

As a great riddler, I've not spoken this word,
for if I had, that'd just be absurd.

After some twisting and thrashing, I'll have solved this problem, 
the four other parts, I'm sure that I've solved them.

The problems the key, I know it, I know it,
But instead of sharing I might as well throw it.

As with the past, a similar method involved,
This time it's much harder, and has greatly evolved.

Conclusion---

With all of these pieces, you look back in time,
This is the end of the puzzle, but not my last rhyme.

What/who am I?

Comment: Are we just attempting to solve for the key, here?  I don't see a question.

Comment: Added what/who am I? ;)

Comment: I think I know what the key is, but I might be forced to throw it at you, since I can't figure out what part 1 is wanting.  Haha

Comment: Haha. This very likely can't be solved without parts 1-4. That was the point in listing that parts 1-4 can be solved out of order. Part 5 can't.

Comment: I knew I needed to throw it at you! :P

Comment: Hahaha. That was quick. I knew you'd already figured out the second half.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is

> Tombstone

Because..

*A good problem solver peers into the past,

once you find me, it's quiet at last.*

> **T**ulip
>  **O**carina
>  **M**ountain
>  **B**utton
>  I used the first letters of each of the previous puzzle's solutions to find the word `Tomb`

Then...

*Completing this riddle is the ultimate test,

for after its done, you will need your rest.*

> Your final resting place is generally in a tomb

*The other day I screamed "JSTYX" out loud all confused,

To figure out what it means, I'd be greatly amused.*

> Subtract 5 from each of the letters of "JSTYX" to get "ENOTS"

*The problems the key, I know it, I know it,

But instead of sharing I might as well throw it.*

*As with the past, a similar method involved,

This time it's much harder, and has greatly evolved.*

> This is STONE backwards
>  A stone is often thrown, rather than shared.
>  Again, we're looking into the past, but this time it's to reverse the word.
>  A stone is hard and is weathered from larger stones, over time.

The only thing I can think of, on the titles, is that they're backwards:

*Large and in charge*

> The word tulip comes from the Persian word, delband, which means Turban - generally worn by a Persian ruler.

*Small and resilient*

> An ocarina is a small, handheld, instrument - often made of metal.

*Immovable object*

> A mountain....well it's not going anywhere anytime soon

*Unstoppable Force*

> The goal of a button is to hold something in place - to keep it from moving

*Breathing New Life*

> This one breaks the pattern, but tombs do feed carrion and other bugs that inhabit graveyards.

Comment: If you can just explain a few more things. See if you can figure out titles. And explain the hints. @Khale_Kitha

Comment: I'll throw you the titles since you got everything else pretty well covered.  So the fifth part of the puzzle... everything is solved in opposites.  The titles all represent the opposite of what they are, but the first 4 are clues to the 5th.  Large or Small, they stand over you (in charge).  They are typically never moved and they last (virtually) forever except in extreme circumstances.  And death is something you can't prevent (unstoppable force)

Comment: Ahh, okay.  That makes sense (Though my title idea fits your backwards theme that this one had, haha.)